how to link toc to the correct section after resetting sectioncounter?
I have a section in my document which would be numbered 7 but I set the section counter to 0 again such that numbering for that section starts at 1, but this means when i click on my toc page for this section , it takes to the other section 1 in my document, would appreciate any help.
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{this is section 7}.

Welcome! Are you able to make your code snippet into a small but complete example we can compile to reproduce the issue? Isn't it rather confusing for readers to have two sections 1?

Redefine  \theHsection so that it expands to something unique for every section. Then hyperref will be happy. By default \theHsection is \arabic{section} and that is not enough here.

Readers would be quite confused if you refer to section 1, because they won't know which one, Do you have higher level divisions, such as parts?

\setcounter{section}{0}
% Redefine \theHsection to include more information
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\thesection.\thepage}
\section{this is section 7}.
I redefined \theHsection to use thepage as unique idenitfier for the hyperref linking and that fixed the issue for me. Thanks @UlrikeFischer for the help.
